# MongoDB - Paging with ranged queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I am currently working on a web application with MongoDB, and it populates the browser with pages of content.

I am aware of the two methods of paging (seen here: https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/):

1) `.skip() + .limit()`

2) `.find({_id > last_id}).limit(n)`

I understand the performance issues with the first solution, so that option was out of the picture.

The second solution works great, but only if the results are sorted by `_id`. If you sort by a non-unique field such as a date, there can be more than one document with that date so some documents may be excluded from the results.

Also, the user must be navigating through the pages linearly because there is a `last_id` variable that constantly needs to be updated and is determined by the `_id` of the last document from the previous page. If the user were to jump from page 1 to 7, page 7 would show the results meant for page 2 because the `last_id` would hold the `_id` from the last document of page 1.

So my question is, how would one implement paging if we were sorting by a non-unique field (such as a Date or a firstName), and how would we allow users to jump multiple pages at once?

Any tips would be greatly appreciate, thank you!

Comment: What kind of load are you running?  Unless your DB has millions and millions of records, you aren't going to notice a performance issue.  Don't over complicate things... just use `find().skip().limit()`.  Make it work first and then optimize it later once you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct, you should be fine with skip unless you know you're going to have a lot of documents. But even if you don't expect much but then get enormously successful/popular you don't want your code to break just is it gets used by millions of users.

If you sort by date and then by id you can do the following:

```
.find(
  {
    date:{
      $lte:lastDate
    },
    _id:{ 
      $lt: lastId 
    }
  }
).limit(n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This solves the problem of not being able to sort by things other than `_id`, so that's great. However, I'm still left with the problem of the possibility of users skipping multiple pages, i.e. user on page 1 goes straight to page 7. In that case, wouldn't the values of `lastDate` and `lastId` be appropriate for page 2, but not page 7?

Comment: @calviners paging can't be done this way, this is more like facebook's infinite scroll. Paging is a bit silly if you offer hundreds of pages anyway. Instead of offering the hundreds of pages maybe offer a better search option. I use google a lot and almost never need to go to page 2.